# React & Leaflet: How do I remove a marker?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I have a react project with typescript and I am trying to implement a marker on my Leaflet map. Currently when a user clicks the map a marker is placed on that position but I also want to implement that when the user clicks the map again the old marker disappears and a new one appears. This is the current state of the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./Map.css";
import markerIconUrl from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";

const Map: React.FC = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState<L.Marker | null>(null);
  const [clickedLocation, setClickedLocation] = useState<L.LatLngExpression | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current && !mapRef.current.hasChildNodes()) {
      const map = L.map(mapRef.current, {
        center: [0, 0], 
        zoom: 2,
        attributionControl: false,
      });

      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        maxZoom: 18,
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        detectRetina: true,
      }).addTo(map);

      // Define the marker icon
      const markerIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: markerIconUrl,
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
      });

      // Add a click event listener to the map
      map.on("click", (e) => {
        console.log(marker);
        if (marker) {
          map.removeLayer(marker);
        }

        const newMarker = L.marker(e.latlng, { icon: markerIcon });
        setMarker(newMarker);
        setClickedLocation([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
        map.addLayer(newMarker);
      });
    }
  }, [marker]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(marker);
  }, [marker]);

  return <div ref={mapRef} id="map"></div>;
};

export default Map;
```

What I don't get is how the first console.log(marker) always is null. What I also don't get is that the useEffect() at the bottom is triggered and that the console.log in that clause shows

```
Object { options: {…}, _latlng: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 39, _mapToAdd: {…}, _map: {…}, _zoomAnimated: true, _events: {…}, _icon: img.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-zoom-animated.leaflet-interactive, _shadow: null, … }
```

How do I remove the old marker and why does the first console.log(marker) always output null?